# is 'settings' a keyword in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

i came across the following code in a jQuery plugin. I have simplified it to take away classes etc. But the [key]word 'settings' keeps appearing:-

```
$(settings['#id1'], this).bind('click', function(){...});


$(settings['box']).fadeOut("fast");

and

$(this).find(settings['#id1']);
```

Is `settings` a keyword here? I can't find it in [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/?s=settings)

Comment: `settings` is no keyword. Why do you say so?

Comment: how do you interpret the above statement then?

Comment: http://gristmill.github.io/jquery-popbox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`popbox.js` line #4](https://github.com/gristmill/jquery-popbox/blob/master/popbox.js#L4)

```
var settings = $.extend({
  selector      : this.selector,
  open          : '.open',
  box           : '.box',
  arrow         : '.arrow',
  arrow_border  : '.arrow-border',
  close         : '.close'
}, options);
```

It really wasn't hard to find.

Comment: my bad, in editing the file, i had deleted it, initially! sorry about that!

Comment: @SangramSingh editing what file? I wouldn't recommend editing 3rd party libraries. You should instead, extend them.